# How do I make the following plot with Seaborn? Grouping a dataframe by columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, visualization

```
    model_name  1   2   3   4   5
0   ground_truth    41.333333   12.000000   12.666667   11.333333   22.666667
1   TL_model    73.333333   4.666667    2.666667    4.666667    14.666667
2   other-model 22.000000   21.333333   9.333333    31.333333   16.000000
```

Assume I have the above dataframe. I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. I would like the x-axis to be [1,2,3,4,5]
2. I would like the y-axis to reflect the frequency of each entry in the dataframe, for example entry [ground_truth][1] -> 41.333 and so on
3. I would like to have 3 bars next to each other for each entry in the x-axis (15 bars in total). That is for x-value 1, I would like the first bar to reflect `ground_truth frequency-> 41.333`, 2nd value to reflect `TL_model's frequency -> 73.3333`; and the last value to reflect `other-model's frequency -> 22.0000`. So that would be 3 bars for value 1, 3 bars for 2,.... all the way to value 5.

How do I do this using Seaborn? I'm struggling quite a lot and can't figure out how to set the "hue" parameter without setting the x and y axis properly. But I'm not sure how to set the y-axis in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'model_name': {0: 'ground_truth', 1: 'TL_model', 2: 'other-model'},
 '1': {0: 41.333333, 1: 73.333333, 2: 22.0},
 '2': {0: 12.0, 1: 4.666667, 2: 21.333333},
 '3': {0: 12.666667, 1: 2.666667, 2: 9.333333},
 '4': {0: 11.333333, 1: 4.666667, 2: 31.333333},
 '5': {0: 22.666667, 1: 14.666667, 2: 16.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

Your problem can be solved in many ways. Since dataframe that draws graph is not large data, using hue by unpivoting is one of the convenient ways. lets `melt` for unpivot.

```
sns.barplot(data=df.melt('model_name'), x='variable', y='value', hue='model_name')
```

output:

[image]